# Third party Ad serving using Google IMA SDK

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, google-api

I am requesting a Third party ad using google interactive media ads SDK.(AS3)

i Get the following error:
Error: ErrorCode: 0 AdError: Unable to request ads from server. Cause: Error #2032: Stream Error.

My question is...does a third party ad tag need to be inside a doubleclick ad wrapper?
and is if yes is there a work around to request the ads from a third party server using Google IMA SDK ?